# ORACLE APEX - Submit Parent Page on Closing only ONE Modal Dialog out of many such Modal Dialogs

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have 4 modal dialogs opening from my parent page by clicking on different icons.

On closing the modal dialog I have an event-close dynamic action on my parent page which causes the  parent page to submit. However, I want this dynamic action to work only when **one** such modal dialog closes and not when the other modal dialogs' close.

I have tried using an Application Item's value, Rows Returned on a condition as the Server Side Condition for the Dynamic Action but nothing seems work.

Some help would be appreciated.

Actions tried:

[image: Dynamic Action Server Side Condtions that I have tried]
  [image: Dynamic Action Server Side Condtions that I have tried]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only thing you want to do is cancel the page submission on the parent page depending on the modal page you open. Just change the dynamic action from "Close Modal" to "Cancel Modal" on modal pages that should not submit the parent page.

Comment: Thanks a ton, that helped!

Comment: I have not tested it, but another alternative to submitting the parent page is using javascript on the modal pages. For this, you would need one more true action after the action of closing the modal. This other true action would execute a javascript like this "parent.apex.submit ('BUTTON_NAME')"